# UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout nested groups with estimated height

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I currently have the following compositional layout defined:

```
func compose() -> NSCollectionLayoutSection {

    let heroItemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
        widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(2/3),
        heightDimension: .estimated(550)
    )

    let heroItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: heroItemSize)

    let sideKickItemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
        widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
        heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(0.5)
    )

    let sideKickItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: sideKickItemSize)

    let sideKickGroupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
        widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1/3),
        heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0)
    )

    let sideKickGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(
        layoutSize: sideKickGroupSize,
        subitems: [sideKickItem, sideKickItem]
    )

    let topGroupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
        widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
        heightDimension: .estimated(550)
    )

    let topGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(
        layoutSize: topGroupSize,
        subitems: [heroItem, sideKickGroup]
    )

    return NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: topGroup)
}
```

Which gives me the following layout:

[image: Current layout]

The ideal situation would be that the green cell (the `heroItem`) has an estimated height which should be leading. The purple cells (the `sideKickItem`) should then be as high as the green one.

I'm not sure why the layout ultimately uses the height `550` as final height, which makes the purple cells be way to large for their content.

So in the end I'd like the layout to be like the following image:

[image: Requested layout]

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
Changes to be made are subtle:

**1.Function must return a UICollectionViewLayout instead of NSCollectionLayoutSection**

- NSCollectionLayoutSection = "A container that combines a set of
  groups into distinct visual groupings."
- UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout = "A layout object that lets you
  combine items in highly adaptive and flexible visual arrangements."

**2.Pass NSCollectionLayoutSection to an UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout**

These changes worked for me:
[image: Blog UICollectionView]

Final Code:

```
//change 1
func compose() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
//change 2
let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: topGroup)    
let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section)
return layout
```

Please accept this as answer if it works.

Comment: You made no change at all? The section returned by my `compose` method is being used in the `sectionProvider` block provided by `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout`—hence I already return a `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` to my UICollectionView (the collection view wouldn't even accept a section as a layout). The things you mention are not part of the problem; the problem is that **all three cells** should be as high as the **largest cell** out of either the green cell _or_ the group of cells on the right--the purple cells. The image you provided still had the same problem and is no fix

Comment: "all three cells should be as high as the largest cell out of either the green cell or the group of cells on the right" - to break down what the code you have shared does: horizontal 2 divisions (2/3 & 1/3)....the 1/3 section is vertically divided in 2-halves. I tried with a tuple(204, "hospital","Other2"),(205,"asdasd","eadsd")...etc...and i have made sure that a tuple is fit into the section.